# How to create/populate /dev/loop* devices?

Tags: udev, loop-device

Background: I am setting up loopaes (see http://loop-aes.sourceforge.net/loop-AES.README) on a new install of Devuan ASCII 2.0.0. I built kernel 4.9.184 with CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP=n as was instructed by loop-AES.README.

It requires /dev/loop devices, however, there are none automatically in /dev:

```
root@devinix:/dev# ls -la loop*
ls: cannot access 'loop*': No such file or directory
```

From the loop-AES.README:

> Workaround for distros that do not create any pre-existing loop block
>   special device nodes: (1) change init scripts run order so that
>   configuration file based loop kernel module loading happens before
>   enabling swap, or (2) re-configure udev pre-create at least one
>   /dev/loop0 block special device node, or (3) create static loop block
>   special device nodes inside /lib/udev/devices/ directory that udev
>   copies to /dev directory.

I would like to do option (3), as it is what makes the most sense to me.

I created the loop devices in /lib/udev/devices:

```
mknod -m660 loop0 b 7 0
mknod -m660 loop1 b 7 1
mknod -m660 loop2 b 7 2
mknod -m660 loop3 b 7 3
mknod -m660 loop4 b 7 4
mknod -m660 loop5 b 7 5
mknod -m660 loop6 b 7 6
mknod -m660 loop7 b 7 7
```

and set ownership

```
chown root.disk /dev/loop*
```

and created loop-control

```
mknod -m600 loop-control c 10 237
```

The loop device 'files' in /lib/udev/devices are now exactly the same as an UberStudent 4.3 (Ubuntu 14.04.1) install has in /dev.

How do I have udev copy them to /dev on boot?

Some other things I've tried are below.

```
root@devinix:/dev# losetup -f
Error: could not find any loop device
```

```
root@devinix:/dev# MAKEDEV -v loop
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
```

Merci d'avance

Comment: Do you see the loop devices in your sysfs? (/sys/)

Comment: root@devinix:/sys# find . -name "\*loop\*"
returns nothing.

Comment: Apart from the kernel, I don't see who is gonna create loop block devs... If your kernel is built without the loop block dev option, how does AES plan on creating the block dev? I'd guess: either they patch the kernel, either they manage to do it in userspace. The README doesn't give a clue on the creation, but only for nodes...

Comment: Please read the README chapter 3: Instructions for building loop.... You have to get that module 'loop.ko' to do its work, the /dev/ nodes part comes after (you can't create nodes to something that doesn't exist)